# Подскажите как нарисовать в css российский флаг

Tags: css

Подскажите как нарисовать в css российский флаг

Comment: [тыц сюда](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+css&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3yrjusqriAhVSxIsKHdaYCbMQ7xYIKSgA&biw=1366&bih=669)

Comment: Не понятно, для какой задачи... пара примеров - - https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/6fngbx9s/

Answer (score 13):

Вариант с анимацией

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF 33%, #0039A6 34%,#0039A6 66%,#D52B1E 67%);
  animation: 1s flag infinite linear both;
  height: 120px;
  width: 20px;
}
@keyframes flag {
  0% {transform:translate(0, 0)}
  50% {transform:translate(0, 2px)}
  100% {transform:translate(0, 0)}
}
a:nth-child(2){animation-delay:0.1s}
a:nth-child(3){animation-delay:0.2s}
a:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0.3s}
a:nth-child(5){animation-delay:0.4s}
a:nth-child(6){animation-delay:0.5s}
a:nth-child(7){animation-delay:0.6s}
a:nth-child(8){animation-delay:0.7s}
a:nth-child(9){animation-delay:0.8s}
```

```html
<a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a>
```

---

То же но с css переменными:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF 33%, #0039A6 34%,#0039A6 66%,#D52B1E 67%);
  animation: 1s flag infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--n) * 0.05s);
  height: 60px;
  width: 4px;
}
@keyframes flag {
  0% {transform:translate(0, -1px)}
  50% {transform:translate(0, 1px)}
  100% {transform:translate(0, -1px)}
}
```

```html
<a style="--n:1"></a><a style="--n:2"></a><a style="--n:3"></a><a style="--n:4"></a><a style="--n:5"></a><a style="--n:6"></a><a style="--n:7"></a><a style="--n:8"></a><a style="--n:9"></a><a style="--n:10"></a><a style="--n:11"></a><a style="--n:12"></a><a style="--n:13"></a><a style="--n:14"></a><a style="--n:15"></a><a style="--n:16"></a><a style="--n:17"></a><a style="--n:18"></a>
```

---

Самый нормальный вариант - программная генерация html

```js
for(var i = 0; i<80; i++) 
  document.body.innerHTML += `<a style="--n:${i}">`
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 33%, #04a 34%, #04a 66%, #d32 67%);
  animation: 0.8s flag infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--n) * 0.01s);
  height: 120px;
  width: 2px;
}
@keyframes flag {
  0% {transform:translate(0, -2px)}
  50% {transform:translate(0, 2px)}
  100% {transform:translate(0, -2px)}
}
```

Comment: Прикольно смотрится :)

Comment: @Qwertiy да, спасибо, и даже пикселизация не сильно вредит, если увеличить амплитуду

Comment: В последнем со срезом какой-то косяк в начале анимации.

Comment: @Qwertiy он во всех вариантах, в последнем больше элементов по этому заметнее..

Comment: Я исправил - не против?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, спасибо, я не подумал про animation fill mode

Answer (score 12):

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8) говорит:

- Отношение ширины флага к его длине составляет 2:3
- Рекомендуемые цвета флага: #FFFFFF #0039A6 #D52B1E

Ну а дальше делаем div с градиентом:

```css
div {
  width: 12em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 33.333%, #0039A6 33.333%, #0039A6 66.667%, #D52B1E 66.667%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #666;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 66.667%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Плюсанул за интересный способ на чистом CSS без `calc()` вычислить высоту в 1,5 раза меньше ширины

Comment: какой-то забавный эффект, белая полоса кажется шире на пару пикселей за счет тени

Comment: @Grundy, да, тоже заметил :)

Answer (score 7):

Например вот так:

```css
.ru_flag{
width:72px;
height:48px;
background:red;
box-shadow:0 0 5px 0 #666;
}
.ru_flag:before,
.ru_flag:after{
display:block;
content:'';
width:100%;
height:33.33333%;
background:white;
}
.ru_flag:after{
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="ru_flag"></div>
```

Comment: Цвета не те. И размеры можно немного поменять.

Answer (score 7):

```css
.flag {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 33.3%, #00f 33.3% 66.6%, #f00 66.6% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: Похоже только я полез за цветами в википедию?) Кстати, ответ почти такой же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, видимо да) плюс Вам за старания) Мы люди простые, через пипетку цвета берём)